# QGLWidget on ubuntu shows nothing

Tags: qt, opengl, ubuntu, qglwidget

I'm using QGLWidget in a project with Qt5 on ubuntu. The class that extends QGLWidget is very simple, just overiding its two virtual protected functions:

Header:

```
class MyGLWidget : public QGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
};
```

Implementation:

```
MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(parent) {
}
void MyGLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
void MyGLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

I created an instance of it and called its show method, expecting a red window to show up, but what I got is:

[image]

The window is transparent, it displays whatever underneath it.

What indeed the problem is, and how can I fix it? (I'm using ubuntu 14.04 64bit, the Qt5.3 is installed from qt-project.org directly)

Comment: Can you try calling `glViewport` from `resizeGL`?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you are trying to do single-buffered rendering in a compositing window manager. Did you allocate a double-buffered pixel format and are you properly swapping buffers? Failing to do both of those things will produce this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem on the same version of Ubuntu and Qt 5.4. I do not know the exact reason but I think it's because the `glClear` command is not being received or executed by the graphics card unless it is followed by other draw commands. I expanded the `paintGL` function to include some classic test code like this:

```
void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
  glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(-20, 20, 20, -20, -1, 1);

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(10, 10, 0);
    glVertex3f(-10, 10, 0);
    glVertex3f(0, -10, 0);
  glEnd();
}
```

With the additional code to render a red triangle, I found that the clear began to work for me when it had not before.